# How to config GCS bucket permission with terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-storage

I want to set permission for service account sa-email.com on bucket bucket_A.

How can I configure as below with terraform?

1. sa-email.com can create file in bucket_A
2. sa-email.com can not delete file in bucket_A

UPDATE:
Now in my project, sa-email is Storage Object Admin.

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "aaaa" {
    member  = "sa-email.com"
    project = "pid"
    role    = "roles/storage.objectAdmin"
}
```

I have about 20 bucket in my project.
I only want to change the permission to one bucket.
Do I have to use google_storage_bucket_iam_member to set for 20 buckets?
Is there a way to do just a little update ?

Update2:
My solution
google_project_iam_member with "conditioon"

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "aaaa" {
    member  = "sa-email.com"
    project = "pid"
    role    = "roles/storage.objectAdmin"
    condition {
        title      = " bucket can  delete "
        expression = "!resource.name.startsWith(\"projects/_/buckets/bucket_can_not_delete\")"
    }
}


resource "google_project_iam_member" "bbbb" {
    member  = "sa-email.com"
    project = "pid"
    role    = "roles/storage.objectCreator"
    condition {
        title      = " bucket can not delete "
        expression = "resource.name.startsWith(\"projects/_/buckets/bucket_can_not_delete\")"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually have to add an error if you need some help rather than looking for an all done solution.

You need a *storage.objects.create* permission only, you dont need to specify it cant delete it, if it doesnt have it.
Which means the role Storage Object Creator suites your need [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles), as it is described in the Google documentation:

Allows users to create objects. Does not give permission to view, delete, or replace objects.
You'll need to use the following resource:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_member" "bucket_A" {
  bucket = "bucket_A"
  role   = "roles/storage.objectCreator"
  member = var.service_accounts
  depends_on = [google_storage_bucket.bucket_A]
}
```

Where var.service_account is your sa-email.com because it'll probably be environment dependent otehrwise you can just add it as string.

Comment: thanks for the reply.Could you please check my update? @Alex